# Concatenar nova linha

Tags: perl

Como adicionar uma nova linha separando os inputs em um script em Perl?

---

Exemplo:

Estou usando o seguinte script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

print 'oi' . '\n' . 'oi,de novo'
```

E chamo pelo `bash` da seguinte forma:

```
perl test.pl > a.txt
```

Ao abrir o arquivo `a.txt` obtenho:

```
oi\noi, de novo
```

Eu esperaria que o arquivo fosse:

```
oi
oi, de novo
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use aspas duplas `"` ao invés de aspas simples `'`, de modo que permita a [interpolação da *string*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interpolation#Perl), `\n` será interpretado como quebra de linha e não literalmente.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

print 'oi' . "\n" . 'oi,de novo'
# print "oi\noi,de novo"
```

Mais informações: [Strings in Perl: quoted, interpolated and escaped](http://perlmaven.com/quoted-interpolated-and-escaped-strings-in-perl)